# Get original key as though without shift modifier

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create keyboard bindings, which work at least similarly on different keyboard layouts. My problem is that the `shift` modifier converts keys into different keys, as detailed in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues

**Is there any way to find out the original key irrespective of the keyboard layout?**
E.g. find out that `.` is pressed when `shift+.` is pressed.

See also this (currently unanswered) quesion: [get shift+numerical keys in qt using qkeyevent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13579815/4069571)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows you can use [`MapVirtualKeyA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) and `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR` to get the unshifted key. `MapVirtualKeyA` needs the virtual key, which can be get using [`QKeyEvent::nativeVirtualKey`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#nativeVirtualKey).

*Note: When pressing modifiers only `QKeyEvent::key()` may report a false character, the virtual key helps to distinguish these cases.*

#### Example

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ke)
{
  const auto vk = ke->nativeVirtualKey();
  const auto unshifted_key = MapVirtualKeyA(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);

  qDebug() << "Original key:" << (char)ke->key();
  qDebug() << "Unshifted key:" << (char)unshifted_key;

  if (unshifted_key > 0) { 
    // Printing the full key sequence just for comparison purposes
    QString modifier;
    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) modifier += "Shift+";
    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) modifier += "Ctrl+";
    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::AltModifier) modifier += "Alt+";
    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::MetaModifier) modifier += "Meta+";
    const QKeySequence ks(modifier + QChar(ke->key()));
    qDebug() << "Full key sequence:" << ks.toString();
  }
}
```

The full source code for the example can be found in [here](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/42632373-get-original-key-as-though-without-shift-modifier).