# With jQuery keyup command how can I tell the difference between "3" and "#" or "2" and "@"?

Tags: jquery, keyup

The title pretty much explains it, but I am simply wondering if there is a way to use keyup to tell my code to react to @ but not 2...same with # and 3.

Right now it gives me the same keycode for 2 and @ which leads to some undesirable behavior.

Anyone know the magic?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Based on the discussions in the comments below with @RobW and @MonkeyZeus, I have learned that while there are several ways to get what I need, the most straight forward answer is to use keypress rather than keyup. If you must use keyup for some reason, then there are some great solutions to detect the shift key in the other answers below.

Thanks,
David

Comment: The keycode for 2 and @ will be the same, you need to check for the shift key.

Comment: can you show code to see what are you trying?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3781142/438992

Comment: As @crnlx pointed out, you can check the shiftKey. You can use the `keydown` event and call `String.fromCharCode` to get the keyCode's value, or you can evaluate what the value is when the keyup event occurs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What if the cursor isn't at the end of the input?

Comment: @KevinB Yea I thought of that just before reading your comment...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `element.selectionStart` and/or `element.selectionEnd` can be used to find the cursor position.

Comment: Of course, this all falls over if someone is using a UK keyboard!

Comment: @RobW I wish I never deleted my comment and you are right. I think for greatest cross-country and cross-keyboard functionality you would need to check the actual character in the `<input>` field to decide what action to take rather than jumping through hoops with keycodes and such

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well, if I really want to detect "@" or "#" via the keyboard (not copy-paste), I would not use any of these methods, but the `keypress` event (*not* `keydown` or `keyup`).

Comment: @RobW Is keypress standardized across all browsers? I've experienced varying differences in terms of which key triggers which event before/after the other events, especially for IE8. Before you tell me to give IE8 the single-finger salute I should let you know that 40% of my user-base is still IE8...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You can rely on `keypress` to be accurate for "@" and "#". Look at the "Remarks" section on [the MSDN article for keypress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/ms536939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see which key strokes are supported in IE (4+!). jQuery normalizes the event object, so you can always use `event.which`.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Can you put your advice in a new reply so I can give you credit for the answer? KeyPress was the magic. I had read somewhere that keypress missed some of the key commands so I have stayed away from it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure I should get the credit? @RobW suggested the `keypress`, I was actually skeptical about it.

Comment: You are right, I would like to give @RobW credit for his answer. There are several ways to skin this cat it seems, but using keypress rather than keyup seems the most straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the Shift press state.

```
$("#id").on("keyup", function(e){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

    if (key == "3" && e.shiftKey) {
        // #
    } else if(key == "2" && e.shiftKey) {
        // @
    }

});
```

Likewise, you can also check `e.ctrlKey`, [`e.metaKey`](http://api.jquery.com/event.metakey/), and `e.altKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion from the comments:

Instead of jumping through hoops with keycode detection and other internationalization issues, it is probably best to check the literal character entered by the user as it is shown in the `<input>` box.

Using a combination of `element.selectionStart`, `element.selectionEnd`, and `substring()` you can check the what is the actual character as rendered by the `<input>` field.

Recognition goes out to Rob W and PeteR for this post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another hat in the ring.  Determining characters in keypress events isn't something that JavaScript does very well right now. Due to it's variability, I'd rather not force any method to have to decipher it inline, and defer evaluation to another method that can be subbed in and out.

The ideal would be a method that takes in the KeyUp [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) as an argument and returns whatever character was pressed: Let's call it `MapKeyPressToActualCharacter`.

Then your code could look super clean like this:

```js
$("#id").on("keyup", function(e){
    switch(MapKeyPressToActualCharacter(e)) {
        case "#":
            //handle #
            break;
        case "@":
            //handle @
            break;
    }
});
```

Now we just have to figure out how to write `MapKeyPressToActualCharacter`.
Here's an implementation based off the answer to [get key char from keycode with shift modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786582/1366033):

```js
function MapKeyPressToActualCharacter(event) {
    var isShiftKey = event.shiftKey;
    var characterCode = event.keyCode;
    var isAlphabetChar = characterCode >= 65 && characterCode <= 90;
    var specialChars = [8,9,13,16,17,18,20,27,91,92];
    var character = "";

    if (valueInArray(characterCode, specialChars)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isAlphabetChar) {
        character = String.fromCharCode(characterCode);
    } else if (isShiftKey) {
        character = GetShiftedCharacters()[characterCode];
    } else {
        character = String.fromCharCode(characterCode);
    }
    return character;
}

function valueInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Bd67a/)

You'll also need to get a mapping of each character and it's shifted corollary with the method `GetShiftedCharacters`:

```js
function GetShiftedCharacters() {
    var characterMap = {32: " ",
                        48: ")",
                        49: "!",
                        50: "@",
                        51: "#",
                        52: "$",
                        53: "%",
                        54: "^",
                        55: "&",
                        56: "*",
                        57: "(",
                        59: ":",
                        107: "+",
                        109: "_",
                        188: "<",
                        190: ">",
                        191: "?",
                        192: "~",
                        219: "{",
                        220: "|",
                        221: "}",
                        222: "\\" };
    return characterMap;
}
```

#### Here's a distributable JS file: [**MapKeyPress.js**](http://kylemitofsky.com/libraries/libraries/MapKeyPress.js)

*Note, since the MapKeyPress function calls `array.indexOf`, you should use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) to extend to older browsers.  Here's a shiv called [indexOfPolyFill.js](http://kylemitofsky.com/libraries/libraries/indexOfPolyFill.js), and here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/3VNKQ/).