# Keycode for text box

Tags: javascript

I got a question, I'm struggling with keycodes.

If i press at the "-" key my text box will filled with "-".

```
if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 173) {
                document.getElementById("uitkomst").value += "-";
            }
```

I want to fill my textbox with *.
There  is no specific keycode for *
The keycodes for 8 and * are the same. How can I find a way for typing * in my textbox?

Comment: Don't use `keycode`, use `key` and compare with `*`.

Comment: yeah @connexo is right. or you can check the input added and then compare it with `*` or whatever and do your thing

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434647/detecting-the-asterisk-key-on-keydown-event

Comment: @Still_learning No, that question is not about Javascript.

Comment: Still no answer for me :(

Comment: *The keycodes for 8 and * are the same* - not on e.g. German keyboards. `keyCode` really doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: It looks like the only way is brute force - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337188/get-key-char-value-from-keycode-with-shift-modifier

Comment: Or try using ASCII codes with the `charCodeAt()` method - I had a look at it and couldn't find a solution, but you may be interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `keyCode`, use `key` and compare with `*`.

```
if (e.altKey && e.key === '*') {
  document.getElementById("uitkomst").value += "*";
}
```

`keyCode` (just as the proprietary `event.which`)  is deprecated and cannot be implemented in a cross-OS, cross-browser and cross-internationalized way. For example the German keyboard has <kbd>*</kbd> left of the enter key and needs to be accessed using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

By the looks of it you're creating a calculator. I'd suggest you list the allowed characters in an array:

```js
const allowedKeys = '+-/*.,0123456789%'.split('');
allowedKeys.push('Enter');
allowedKeys.push('Backspace');
allowedKeys.push('Delete');
allowedKeys.push('ArrowLeft');
allowedKeys.push('ArrowRight');
allowedKeys.push('ArrowUp');
allowedKeys.push('ArrowDown');

const allowedKeysWithCtrl = 'acvx'.split('');
allowedKeysWithCtrl.push('Home');
allowedKeysWithCtrl.push('End');
allowedKeysWithCtrl.push('PageDown');
allowedKeysWithCtrl.push('PageUp');

calculator.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if (!e.ctrlKey && allowedKeys.includes(event.key)) return;
  if (e.ctrlKey && allowedKeysWithCtrl.includes(event.key)) return;
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<textarea id="calculator"></textarea>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, if i press * it doesn't add it to the textbox.

Comment: @Goks Which browser are you using? The Javascript uses a syntax only understood by evergreen browsers (no version of IE). Let me rewrite it for compatibility with old browsers. Edit: Done.

Comment: No sir, I'm  using Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I used the" if (e.altKey && e.key === '*') {
  document.getElementById("uitkomst").value += "*";
}" you wrote. if I press * nothing happens.

Comment: You don't want to check for `altKey`. Remove that. On German keyboards, you access `*` with Shift. No need to check for which key was pressed - only which character that is supposed to generate. Also, instead of adding the character to the textbox' value yourself, simply allow the keyboard event to happen if a legal character was entered. Otherwise, use `e.preventDefault` and no character will appear.